# More than one Regexoptions in single match?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Is there any option to use more than one REgexOptions in a single **Regex.Match** method ?

Suppose i want to use **RegexOptions.IgnoreCase** and **RegexOptions.Singleline** in a Regex.Match method.

I want just like this....

```
Match m=Regex.Match(input,pattern, more than one regexoptions);
```

Is it possible ? If yes how can I do this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx

Comment: This sounds like a homework question. How can you know about `RegexOptions`.`IgnoreCase` without knowing about `|`? You should tag it as homework if so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As with all enumeration types representing bit flags, you may use the bitwise OR operator, `|`, to combine multiple flags:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(
    input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline );
```

Refer to [Enumeration Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx) on MSDN for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex.Match(subjectString, @"regex", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what the `FlagsAttribute` implies on an `enum`.